# Why does select and exec give different results for aggregate-function column

Tags: kdb

At first glance the next two queries should give the same result:

```
q)exec a from select sum[a] from ([]a:1 2)
,3
q)exec sum[a] from ([]a:1 2)
3
```

but as we see, their return types are different.

Why the `exec` in this example does not act like a regular `select` (just without column name)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

select returns columns which must be lists, not atoms. Your `sum` returns an atom but kdb recognizes this aggregation and it automatically enlists your atom under the covers. E.g.

```
/this works even though sum would return an atom
select sum[a] from ([]a:1 2)
/this doesn't work because kdb doesn't recognize the aggregation function
select {sum x}[a] from ([]a:1 2)
/this works by manually enlisting
select {enlist sum x}[a] from ([]a:1 2)
```

The list of recognized aggregations for which this occurs is `.Q.a0`.

So in case 1 you've forced a hidden enlist and when you exec it out it's still enlisted, in case 2 there's no hidden enlist since exec doesn't mandate column/list output, i.e. it allows atom output

Comment: It's wonderful Terry! Thanks again! But how do you get this intel about `.Q.a0`?

Comment: Found it here: https://code.kx.com/q/basics/qsql/#special-functions

Comment: Previously it was in a wiki: see ref in https://groups.google.com/g/personal-kdbplus/c/vPosmdAAUj4. But is there any description of `Q.a0`, `a1` and `a2` anywhere now?

Comment: a good case to read `q.k` thoroughly for me :)

Comment: Good find. That's the best documentation you're going to get on .Q.a012. Officially they're not supposed to be messed with so they won't be documented

Answer (score 3):

In case 1 you are first creating a table of length 1 by applying the `sum` function to the `a` column within the select statement (the output of a `select` statement is always a table).

You are then running `exec` to pull the raw column (which is a list of length 1) from that table.

In case 2 you are directly accesing the `a` column within the `exec` statement and performing the `sum` aggregation on this list. The result will thus be a scalar.

The `select` in the first piece of code is creating an intermediary table which is not present in the second piece of code.

With regards the return types this is also a somewhat special-case example of `exec` where you are only requesting one column. If you aggregated multiple columns the result would be a dictionary (again comprised of scalar values):

```
q)t:([]a:1 2 3;b:4 5 6)
q)exec sum a,sum b from t
a| 6
b| 15
```